# Set TextView based on Volley Response in Android

Tags: android, android-volley, android-json

I am using `Volley` in application.I am getting `name,email,phone` values from Volley `response`.The condition is if `name` and `email` value is `null`, I want to set `phone` value in `TextView`.If `name` and `phone` value is `empty`, I want to set `email` in TextView. if `phone` and `email` is empty,I want to set `name` in TeextView.
This is `JSON` response

```
{
    "id": 25,
    "email": "aa@gmail.com",
    "phone": null,
    "full_name": ""
}
```

This is how I have parsed `JSON`

```
 JsonObjectRequest foodie_request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                                {
                                    try {

                                        String fullName = response.getString("full_name");
                                        String phone=response.getString("phone");
                                        String email=response.getString("email");
                                        if(email.trim().equals("") && fullName.trim().equals(""))
                                        {
                                            entry.setName(phone);
                                        }
                                       else  if(phone==null && fullName.trim().equals(""))
                                        {
                                            entry.setName(email);
                                        }
                                        else if(email.trim().equals("") && phone==null  ) {
                                            entry.setName(fullName);
                                        }

                                       // progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
```

How to do this ?

Comment: What is error in this?

Comment: every time it is setting name in TextView if available in response.But not setting email and phone if it is available and name is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(fullName)) {
            entry.setText(phone);
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phone) && TextUtils.isEmpty(fullName))
        {
            entry.setText(email);
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
            entry.setText(fullName);
        }
```

Try with this, **TextUtils.isEmpty(str)** also check the null value so no need to further loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
if(fullName.isEmpty() && fullName != null && email.isEmpty() && email != null)
    textView.setText(phone);
if(fullName.isEmpty() && fullName != null && phone.isEmpty() && phone != null)
    textView.setText(email);
if(email.isEmpty() && email != null && phone.isEmpty() && phone != null)
    textView.setText(fullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not get value null from database according to your question otherwise you will get NullPointerException get a blank string and try this one.

```
JsonObjectRequest foodie_request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {

                    String fullName = response.getString("full_name");
                    String phone = response.getString("phone");
                    String email = response.getString("email");

                    if (fullName.toString().trim().length() == 0 && email.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                        entry.setName(phone);
                    } else if (fullName.toString().trim().length() == 0 && phone.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                        entry.setName(email);
                    } else if (phone.toString().trim().length() == 0 && email.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                        entry.setName(fullName);
                    }

                    // progressDialog.dismiss();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Try using this, hope it helps.